# Relation between transtive, minimal and uniquely ergodic systems

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples, ergodic-theory

I was wondering whether about several dynamical notions, and their relations.

I am considering a amenable second countable Hausdorff group $G$, with Haar measure which acts topologically on a compact Hausdorff space $X$, where the action is $\alpha:G\times X \to X$. I am interested in the following notions:

- **Topological tranistitvity:**  I say that the action is topological transitive, if there exists an $x_0\in X$ such that $\{ \alpha(g,x_0): g\in G \}$ is dense in $X$.
- **Minimality:**   I say that the action is minimal, if $\{ \alpha(g,x): g\in G \}$ is dense in $X$ for all $x\in X$.
- **Unique ergodicity:** I say that the action is uniquely ergodic, if there is a unique Borel probability invariant measure.

I'm wondering what is the relation between these notions with counter examples. It is clear that minimality implies topological transitivity and I'm aware of examples where the reverse implications does not hold. I was specifically wondering how unique ergodicity relates to these two properties.

I saw a lot of examples where the systems are minimal and uniquely ergodic, but I was wondering whether you can deduce one from the other under some mild conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A uniquely ergodic system whose unique invariant measure is of full support is minimal.

For a uniquely ergodic system that is not minimal, just take a contraction $x \mapsto x/2$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I see how the first statement you say hold, but can you explain why the contraction is uniquely ergodic?

Comment: Given a continuous $f$, note that $f(T^k(x))\rightarrow f(0)$ for all $x$. So the same is true for the Birkhoff sums of $f$. Then integrate with respect to an invariant measure $\mu$. You get $\int f d\mu = f(0)$. Hence $\mu$ is the Dirac measure at the origin.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks.